Can Synergy work if two computers have the same computer name?
Can Synergy work if two computers have the same computer name?
I have two computers, both with a bunch of notepad windows open so I can't restart them.
Both have the same computer name set in Windows.  (The Windows is Windows 7). I think changing computer name requires a restart and that's not an easy option in this situation.
I know that normally Synergy can be and is used to use one computer's Mouse/trackpad, to access multiple   computers/screens.
But  can Synergy be used here given that the two computers have the same computer name set in Windows?

Yes it still works.
The windows configured computer name is irrelevant.
What counts is the computer name configured within synergy under "preferences". Make that different as that's the name that Synergy uses, and it's fine.
